# Eclipse: Cannot run program "make" (in directory "[path is given]")

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, mingw

I have Windows 64bit. I have installed Java 64bit and Eclipse 64bit.

I have also installed MinGW located at C:\MinGW.

I have wrote a simple hello world project, but I am getting an error  Cannot run program "make" (in directory "[path is given]")...

What should I do ?

Comment: Eclipse is looking for a program called 'make.exe'. Check your mingw to see if it installed make. If it did is your windows path set so it can be found?

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon your same problem and nothing I did seemed to work. But now I finally make it work. I’m answering just in case somebody passes through this post and ti somehow helps.
I tried through the command line first. I opened a command line, wrote make –version and that seemed to work, so I went to [path provided] and typed `make all`. This gave me a windows error (some kind of error more like a javascript alert) telling me I didn’t have zlib1.dll

After a lot of research in the net I downloaded this dll (because my mysys inside mingw didn’t have it) from their [web page](http://www.zlib.net/) I just copy/pasted the dll inside the bin folder. 
This make the command line make all work. But no the eclipse one. I found a few solutions, like deleting the mingw make (there is a mingw-make.exe) or restarting a hundred time or changing from 64 to 32 bits (not an option for me), but nothing seemed to work. Until I found this in the [eclipse forums](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=171630/).

It seems that in the c/c++ build --> builder settings --> uncheck ‘use default build command’ and then in build command you put the path to the make.exe like in ‘C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make’ it will work.

Of course you need to go to the tool chain editor (pending from the c/c++ build in the project properties) and change the current builder to GNU Make Build.

I hope this helps anybody that comes in the future!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I found that the path in the Eclipse C/C++ build environment was added correctly for the Make Build. Looking from Eclipse properties.

If I ran make from the command line in my directory it failed!

I noticed that the path was not added in the Windows System Properties Environment Variable as expected.
I added manually the 2 paths (Build Tools Folder and Tool Chain Folder) into the windows system and it worked.